# Http settings for Processmakers

Tags: processmaker

I know there is a way to set your processmaker in such you can access it by using the following format:

```
processmaker.example.com
```

But is there a way to configure it in such you can access it by using:

```
example.com/processmaker/
```

Thank you and good day.

Answer (score 1):

ProcessMaker is configured to respect the structure: xxx/sysworkflow/en/classic/login/login, so changing it to:

`http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/processmaker/`

it won't work unlike wordpress that you have the possibility to create subfolders.

In the case of ProcessMaker domains or ports are created to have access. In your case you can create a rule to redirect your URL to processmaker login, it means when you enter to

`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/processmaker/`

it redirects to:

`xxx/sysworkflow/en/classic/login/login`

You need to modify your `.htaccess` file or `pmos.conf` file depending on how you installed ProcessMaker.

[This information](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file?) may help you to redirect your URL.

Regards.

[processmaker](/questions/tagged/processmaker)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, ProcessMaker needs to be on the root of any server configuration. This is due to the .htaccess configuration file, which goes to sysGeneric.php.

Another problem is that the application uses full paths (e.g. /js/maborak.js) and it won't work on a folder unless you modify the templates.